# PhpWord table no border

Tags: php, phpword

I've added a table to a phpword file but seem to be unable to change the border of the table. I read that borderSize is a cell specific setting but even there no change. The border doesn't change at all. I've tried numerous things here on stack overflow but can't seem to find the solution. Did anyone run into a similar problem before?

```
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($file);
$styleTable = array('borderColor'=>'#CCC', 'borderSize'=> 2, 'cellMargin'=>50, 'valign'=>'center');
$styleFirstRow = array('bgColor'=>'#CCC', 'bold'=>true, 'size'=>11, 'valign'=>'center');
$styleCell = array('valign'=>'center');
$fontStyle = array('bold'=>false, 'align'=>'center', 'color'=>'ccc');

$phpWord->addTableStyle('myTable', $styleTable, $styleFirstRow);

$section = $phpWord->createSection();
$table = $section->addTable('myTable');

$table->addRow(900);
$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('#SIG01_100_200#', $fontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText('#SIG02_100_200#', $fontStyle);

$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save($file_pdf);
```

Comment: Looks like the borderStyle definition is indeed effecting the cells only and that there seems to be a minimum size always applied (it does work as expected when you increase the value). I'm not sure what is your goal exactly with the "no border table", but one way to produce a seemingly "borderless" table style is to set the borderColor to match your background color (white probably).

Answer (score 3):

Set border color and border size for every side of every cell:

```php
$styleCell =
[
    'borderColor' =>'ff0000',
    'borderSize' => 6,
];
```

```php
$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell);
```

or

```php
$styleCell =
[
    'borderTopColor' =>'ff0000',
    'borderTopSize' => 6,
    'borderRightColor' =>'ff0000',
    'borderRightSize' => 6,
    'borderBottomColor' =>'ff0000',
    'borderBottomSize' => 6,
    'borderLeftColor' =>'ff0000',
    'borderLeftSize' => 6,
];
```

```php
$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell);
```